# Got bug: Circular view path [dmno]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/dmno] again. Check your ViewResolver setup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

[Here is Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF5a3.png)

Here is my Controller

```
@Controller
public class tdlController  {
    @Autowired
    TdlService tdlService;

    @GetMapping("/dmno")
    public String homepage(Model model) throws RuntimeException {
       // model.addAttribute("list",tdlService.findAll());
        return "dmno";
    }
    @RequestMapping("GetData2")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ListtodoEntity> findAll(){
        return tdlService.findAll();
    }
}
```

I tried many ways in here but not worked. Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of your dmno file from `.jsp` to `.html` and move your `dmno.html` to the following location

```
src/main/resources/templates/dmno.html
```

Also make sure that you have these dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- TODO: Add dependency for mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency will handle rendering of your html files

Comment: Thank you. It 's done. But why and how to do that with jsp ???

Comment: JSP was used long time ago when we were developing servlets, it has been replaced with HTML and Thymeleaf, it offers the same functionalities like iterating through objects and it comes prebuilt with spring boot.

Comment: There are some workarounds to use JSP but since you are just learning Spring I would advise you to stick with Thymeleaf and HTML.